# Running Tensorflow model model_main_tf2.py has SyntaxError

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I use tensorflow models to train my dataset, running

```
python3 model_main_tf2.py \
    --model_dir=/home/123/Documents/tf//train \
    --pipeline_config_path=/home/123/Documents/tf/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config \
    --alsologtostderr
```

in terminal, a few min has an error :

```
File "/home/123/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/models/official/vision/image_classification/efficientnet/efficientnet_model.py", line 44
    input_filters: int = 0
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I try to change to

```
input_filters = int(0)
```

it ok, but has another wrong, so I change back. Maybe python version does not match or something else, I have no idea.

my python version is 3.5.2, tensorflow version is CPU 2.1.0

Comment: Try updating your python to 3.6.X or 3.7.X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is using [type hints on variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/). The minimum Python version to support these is 3.6, so you need to upgrade your Python installation (Python 3.5 is by now *quite* old).